# Android Programming prerequisites

Tags: android

I'm new to the android. What are the exact pre-requisites for android programming. As I know the basics of java, will it be helpful in learning the android programming?

Comment: Yes. It will be helpful. The only pre-requisite are willingness to learn and your interest. Start from basic. Follow the tutorial and slowely you'll get hold of things. This question might be closed as it might  not fit into the type of questions you may ask here.

Comment: Syntax never matters, what you need to know is way to code; forming algorithms, Android is a mere api of Java, best tutorials out there are references from Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it'll be. How can you develop Android app without knowing java? [DEITEL- Android How to Program](http://www.deitel.com/Books/Android/AndroidHowtoProgram/tabid/3634/Default.aspx)
will give you the basic java you need to start android development. But sooner or latter, it would help if you take java seriously. Resources are rampant on the web, just google them.

Comment: Well, surprising as it may be, you can learn Java while also learning app development :)

Answer (score 1):

Google around for tutorials. I learnt Android with no experiance in Java.
Take a look at these site 
http://www.vogella.com/android.html

http://developer.android.com/index.html

Comment: Haha looks as though we did pretty much the same :)

Comment: True! Didnt see your Answer when I posted mine!

Comment: Neither did I see yours :)